# Reading lines from file using SeekableByteChannel

Tags: java

Can I use SeekableByteChannel for reading lines from file. I have the position (in bytes) and want to read the whole line. for example I use this method for RandomAccessFile

```
private static String currentLine(String filepath, long currentPosition)
{
   RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(filepath, "rw");

  byte b = f.readByte();
  while (b != 10)
  {
    currentPosition -= 1;
    f.seek(currentPosition);
    b = f.readByte();
    if (currentPosition <= 0)
    {
      f.seek(0);
      String currentLine = f.readLine();
      f.close();
      return currentLine;
    }
  }
  String line = f.readLine();
  f.close();
  return line;  

}
```

How can I use something like this for SeekableByteChannel, and will be it faster for reading huge numbers of lines?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `SeekableByteChannel` to read huge files, like 3gb, and works very well...

```
try {
    Path path = Paths.get("/home/temp/", "hugefile.txt");
    SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(path,
        StandardOpenOption.READ);
    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(941);// line size
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = sbc.read(bf)) > 0) {
        bf.flip();
        System.out.println(new String(bf.array()));
        bf.clear();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Use for instead of while please!

Comment: But this required all lines to have the same length?!

Comment: Lets suppose that the line length inside the file is unknown. whats the better way to implement the ByteBuffer.allocate(???). thx

Comment: The buffer size is way to specific for almost every usecase, don't use the code like this to read lines